# Use detectron2 model_convert.py to convert the trained mask-rcnn model file .pth to .pb file error

Tags: caffe

Colab error message: "Dataset 'fruits_nuts' is not registered! But I use register_coco_instances function registered. Can someone help me? thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: colab:https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PcXHWBk8ns01PowOarNEYdtLMuZXR7ro?usp=sharing